# Azure B2C with Web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-ad-b2c

The examples I've seen for using Azure B2C with Web API show app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication (as shown below), however my ASP .NET 5 Web API project uses IApplicationBuilder (not IAppBuilder) and UseOAuthBearerAuthentication does not exist. I've tried app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication, however I believe this uses cookies and I couldn't get it working using a Xamarin app as a client. I've tried app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication but I believe this is for standard Azure AD (not B2C) is that true? Any ideas how to get Azure B2C working with the very latest ASP .NET Web API?

Thanks!!!

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {   
        TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // This is where you specify that your API only accepts tokens from its own clients
            ValidAudience = clientId,
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {   
            // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, "v2.0", discoverySuffix, commonPolicy)))
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. I hope it helps someone else who is looking to use Azure B2C with the latest .NET Web API framework:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IApplicationBuilder app, IOptions<PolicySettings> policySettings)
{
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[my-tenant].onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_my-signup-signin-policy",
        Audience = "[My-Azure-App-Guid]",
        Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated= ctx =>
            {
                var nameClaim = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Principal.FindFirst("name");
                if (nameClaim != null)
                {
                    var claimsIdentity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Principal.Identity;
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, nameClaim.Value));
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://dzimchuk.net/post/setting-up-your-aspnet-core-apps-and-services-for-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: This answer appears to use .NetCore. Any solutions using standard .Net Jwt library?

Answer (score 0):

If the JWT token is available in your client, then you can use JwtBearerAuthentication in the Web API. The JWT issued by Azure B2C ( social logins) can be used as a token to get authenticated in the Web API.

Refer to https://github.com/sendhilkumarg/AzureB2CWebAppAndAPIAuthentication
In this sample the client is a web app